# Custom Editor using kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to built an editor using kineticjs. There are some options like add text and adding styles to the added text like bold underline. is there any option to set bullets in text style?

like this one

- List item
- List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use power of UTF8 with `•` char

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    fill : "black",
    text : "• item 1\n• item 2"
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/2QeM5/1/

Update: also you may use html to image convertion, then you can add image to canvas. See: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/sDp6C/

Comment: +1 for the bulleted list.  But since the questioner says they want to build a text editor you might warn them that html canvas has limited text styling and formatting capabilities (no native underline for example and no wordwrap for paragraphs). ;-)

Comment: You right. May be using html (as image, crazy) inside canvas will be more helpfull.